# Creating Virtual Environment in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-20.04

I want to create a virtual environment in my pc to install my other versions of PHP, Mysql, Cakephp etc. without disturbing my existing installation of the same.

Is it possible?

I have projects related to above languages from more than one version and I do not want to disturb my existing installation to open and work on those projects.

- OS: UBUNTU 20.04 LTS x64
- Coding experience: Somewhere between beginner and intermediate

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of VM tools available for Linux/Ubuntu. You might consider Virtual Box: https://www.virtualbox.org/